# sentencia sql para filtrar en otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas: paciente y reservaciones.

en la tabla reservaciones esta el id del paciente y la fecha de la reservacion necesito ayuda con una sentencia sql que me indique todos los clientes que tengan reservacion el dia de hoy, osea que me busque el id en la tabla cliente y que si ese id esta en la tabla reservaciones y la fecha en la tabla reservaciones es del dia de hoy me lo muestre. algo como:

```
select * from pacient where pacient_id = pacient_id_reserv and date(date_at)=dateNOW(()).
```

Se que esa sentencia no es la que funciona pero es para que tengan mas o menos una idea de lo que necesito.

tengo en `php` un proyecto en que llamo los clientes con algo como esto:

```html
class PacientData {
 public static $tablename = "pacient";
    public static $tablenamer = "reservations";
  
   public static function getAll(){
  $sql = "select * from ".self::$tablename." order by created_at desc";
  $query = Executor::doit($sql);
  return Model::many($query[0],new PacientData());
 }
```

Comment: Prueba algo como esto: `select * from pacient p INNER JOIN reservation r ON p.pacient_id = r.pacient_id_reserv WHERE r.date(date_at)=dateNOW()` Aquí asumo que la tabla se llama `reservation` y que la columna que relaciona a dicha tabla con `patient` se llama `r.pacient_id_reserv`. Otra cosa, si la columna `date_at` es del tipo `DATETIME` no tienes que convertirla con `date`. Y, aquí `dateNOW()` representa la fecha actual en tu contexto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumo que la tabla de pacientes y la tabla de reservaciones tienen cada uno su propio id y las reservaciones tienen una clave foránea dentro de la tabla pacientes.

Una alternativa sería:

```
SELECT *
FROM pacientes 
WHERE id_reservacion IN (SELECT id_reservacion FROM reservaciones WHERE fecha = CURDATE())
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, no tienes la menor idea de lo importante que ha sido este aporte, te lo agradezco infinitamente.